# How can python access the process name that is passed to execl as the second argument

Tags: python, os.execl

Consider the following script saved as `test.py`:

```
from sys import argv, executable
from os import execl

print(argv)
if argv[1] == 'a':
    argv[1] = 'b'
    print('execl')
    execl(executable, 'process_name', *argv)
    print('the interpreter will never get to this line!')
```

Here is the result of running the script:

```
$ python3 test.py a
['test.py', 'a']
execl
['test.py', 'b']
```

I'm curious about what happens to `'process_name'`? Does the new python process store it somewhere so it can be read?

I've tried `psutil.Process(os.getpid()).name()` but it returns `'python.exe'` both times.